# Joining threads before program termination

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a vector of threads that I collect during the execution of my application. To avoid some nasty behavior, I'm trying to ensure every thread is completed when the main thread exits. I tried to call `std::thread::join` on each thread in the vector upon a termination event, but it seems to get stuck if the most recent thread hasn't finished its work and won't stop blocking even after it should. It's important to note that `ThingMaker::CreateThing` reads frames from a series of video files and writes them all to one video, so I know the thread should finish its work in less time than the length of the video clip being created.

```
std::vector<std::thread> threadList;
while (!done)
{
    switch (triggerEvent)
    {
        case 'h': // Spawn new thread to make a thing "in the background"
        {
            ThingMaker next_thing = new ThingMaker();
            threadList.push_back(std::thread(&ThingMaker::CreateThing, next_thing));
            next_thing = NULL;
            break;
        }
        case 't': // Terminate the application
        {
            std::vector<std::thread>::iterator threads;
            for (threads = threadList.begin(); threads != threadList.end(); ++threads)
                threads->join();
            done = true;
            break;
        }
        default: break;
    }
}
```

If I send a 't' before the most recent thread has finished making the video clip and thus finished altogether, `threads->join()` blocks forever. However, if i wait for all video clips to be created, the application terminates. To my understanding, it should simply wait for the thread to finish its work and then let the main thread carry on - is this a misunderstanding?

Comment: Looks ok, maybe one of your threads is not finishing?

Comment: @RichardCritten Due to the nature of the thing I'm creating, the most recent thread is always the last one to finish.

Comment: "it seems to get stuck if the thread hasn't finished" - ehh, yes. That's what `join` *does*. It waits for the thread to finish. How is that a surprise?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Sorry, I might not have been clear enough: the program hangs up completely. It never stops blocking.

Comment: Orthogonal: You might wrap `std::tread` in a lightweight (movable) class that, in the destructor, calls `.join()` unless moved from. If your container is static, this will happen approx. at exit automagically.

Comment: Does the joined thread ever finish? If not, that would explain the join never returning and the application never terminating.

Comment: @JesperJuhl No, the thing I'm making never gets made.

Comment: What does this mean `...and all but crashes`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The program never crashes, but it gets stuck forever on `threads->join()`.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it is off-topic. You are asking why your threads can't be joined, but haven't shown what the thread is doing. Have the threads finished running yet? Calling `join()` doesn't stop them, it just makes `main()` block until they decide to stop  themselves. Does that happen?

Comment: @JonathanWakely I'll make a different question with a little more context - my apologies. I can't go into great detail.

Comment: Don't make a different question, improve this one.

Comment: @networkdrift: You need to show us the "boiled-down" implementation of `ThingMaker::CreateThing` or whatever code the threads are running. You commented "the most recent thread is always the last one to finish". That is usually impossible to guarantee unless the threads are synchronizing with each other in executing the code. If that is the case, that code may result in a deadlock that is causing the behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. The thread simply hasn't finished yet. You can add logging to your code or use a debugger to see whether this is the case.
2. The thread that called `join` holds some lock that is preventing the other thread from finishing. Calling `join` waits for a thread to finish and cannot be safely called unless you're absolutely sure that thread that calls `join` holds no locks the other thread might need to acquire in order to finish. (Look closely at the call stack leading to the call to `join` to see if this is a posssibility.)

Comment: 3. A thread in the list is not `joinable()` and so the result of calling `join()` is undefined (and could block forever).

Comment: It was 1. After some mental gymnastics, I figured out it was a subtle issue with resource management.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues in your code:

- The `join()` on an active thread will wait that the thread is finished before continuing anything.  So if you have no mechanism  to to tell your threads to stop (e.g. a shared atomic variable), you'll wait forever.
- Your `threadlist` vector is **inside** the while loop, so that it's a new list on every occurence.  What happens to the thread that you have pushed into it ? It gets destroyed, and as `join()` wasn't called, it will  `terminate()` your programme.

Comment: It's not UB, it will terminate if the vector goes out of scope before the threads it contains are joined. Apparently the code we've been shown isn't even close to the real code, since the real program isn't terminating.

Comment: Sorry, the vector inside the while loop was my mistake. It's actually a member of a class.

Comment: @JonathanWakely The real code functions the exact same way.

Comment: Unless I am understanding your answer incorrectly, that's what I'm trying to do - I need the main thread to wait for the most recent thread in the vector to finish.

Comment: You've just edited the code to move the vector outside the loop ... so it wasn't accurate then.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Correct - it was a simple mistake when I was writing the trivialized code.

Comment: _"I need the main thread to wait for the most recent thread in the vector to finish."_ And that's what it's doing. So if it doesn't exit, then the thread hasn't finished.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117964/discussion-between-network-drift-and-jonathan-wakely).

Comment: @JonathanWakely you're right about UB: the termination is a perfectly defined behavior in this case.  I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

With `std::thread` you must ensure that each thread is *made unjoinable* (that typically means calling .join()), exactly once. Clearly, a call to `.join()` will wait for that thread to complete. Start a debug session and have a look what each of the threads are doing.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown (which is still woefully incomplete and so we're just guessing) doesn't remove `thread` objects from the vector after you join them. That means you will try to rejoin an already joined thread on the next time through the loop. Trying to join a thread that is not joinable has undefined behaviour. It could block forever (because there is no such thread so it can never be joined).

You should either:

- only try to join threads that are joinable:

  ```
  case 't': // Terminate the application
  {
      for (auto& t : threadList)
      if (t.joinable())
          t.join();
      done = true;
      break;
  }
  ```
- or remove the threads from the list after they've been joined:

  ```
  case 't': // Terminate the application
  {
      for (auto& t : threadList)
          t.join();
      threadList.clear();
      done = true;
      break;
  }
  ```

Comment: This answer is irrelevant because as I've said in my question, the 't' case signals termination - I don't need to worry about the vector after I leave the while loop. However, I did discover that my thread was blocking forever due to resource video files never getting made - so you were right on that point.

Comment: So **everybody** was right when they told you that the reason was probably that a thread hadn't finished. Funny that ;)